# Counting Number Of Classifieds In Category

Tags: php

I have a table `categories` that has: `id, name, subcategory_id, parent_id`.  Another table `classifieds` that has: `classified_id, title, description, category_id`.

I am trying to to pull numbers of classifieds in each category. So it will look like this.

- Accessories(10)
- Cars(15)
- Dating(12)

I gave it a try like this:

```php
enter $catquery  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE sub_id = '0' ORDER BY name ASC"); here

enter  $catrows = mysql_num_rows($catquery);  here
enter $catrows = mysql_num_rows($catquery); here
enter $query = "SELECT category_id, COUNT(title) AS `total` FROM classifieds WHERE classified_id = 'category_id' "; here
enter $result = mysql_query($query); here
enter while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $num_items_in_category[$row['category_id']] = $row['total'];  here

enter } echo "<li><a href='category.php?cat=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']. $row['total']. "</a></li>"; here
```

Thanks fellas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you're looking for by joining the 2 tables.

```
SELECT a.name, count(*) as cnt
FROM categories a
    join classifieds b
    on a.id = b.category_id
group by a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

COUNT is an aggregate function, so you can get all of the counts at once.

I believe what you are looking for is

```
$query = "SELECT category-id, COUNT(title) AS `total` FROM classifieds WHERE classified-id = 'category-cat' GROUP BY category-id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $num_items_in_category[$row['category-id']] = $row['total']; 
}
```

This will give you associative array with the count of records for each category-id